# Correct use of either in a conversation

Tags: adverbs, conversation

In the following conversation:

```
Person A: I don't like Bob
Person B: No, he's annoying. Mind you I don't like Barry, either.
```

It is my understanding that the use of the word "either" is appropriate. As, according to Oxford English dictionary, either can be defined as:

```
2 [adverb, with negative] used to indicate a similarity or link with a tatement just made:
 You don’t like him, do you? I don’t either it won’t do any harm, but won’t really help either
for that matter; moreover:
 I was too tired to go. And I couldn’t have paid, either
```

In this case, either is being used in the "for that matter; moreover" context.

I am having it argued to me that the use of the word either is not appropriate here as it is said by Person B in response to person A's original statement of not liking Bob, and saying "I don't like Barry either" in direct response to "I don't like Bob" doesn't make sense. I believe that as Person B has already agreed with Person A's initial assessment of Bob, the use of the word "either" when referring to Barry is totally valid. That is that the "either" being used by Person B is in fact relating to Person B's first sentence and not in direct response to what Person A originally said.

Comment: Tell the person arguing this to you that they should revise their linguistic theory to include linguistic facts and throw away the rules that don't fit them. Language is not the same as [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf); it also includes [syntax and pragmatics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Semantics.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching your reference is another from [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/either)

> **adverb**
> 5.
> also; too; as well; to the same degree (used after negative clauses coordinated by and, or,  or nor,  or after negative subordinate clauses): He's not fond of parties, and I'm not either. If you don't come, she won't come either.

In this sense, your usage is quite acceptable, as demonstrated by the examples given.